# Can I specify a wildcard or regex as a Directory in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

We have many, many sites, all of which contain a "customer/uploadsfolder".  We have to allow uploading, but want to block any GIF files, as well as turn off PHP in the folder as shown below.  The question is, do we need one entry for every folder, or can wildcards/regex be used?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /customer/uploadsfolder>
        deny from all
        <Files ~ "^\w+\.(gif)$">
            order deny,allow
            allow from all
        </Files>  
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_flag engine off
        </IfModule>      
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use LocationMatch (or "Location ~").

```
<LocationMatch "\/customer\/uploadsfolder\/.*\.(php|gif)">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: So, instead of <directory customer/uploads> it would be <LocationMatch "customer/uploads">  ?  The folders are all several levels down, does that matter?  i.e. root/somesite/projects/customer/uploads"

Comment: Sorry, I'm weak with Regex, and iffy with htaccess, but we're getting bombarded with these GIF files with malware while we figure out the right solution

Comment: for my latest edit, it will match .gif and .php files when /customer/uploadsfolder appears _anywhere_ in the URI.

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver...i hate asking entry level questions without having beat it up for awhile, but I'm in a pinch here today....thanks SO much.